Deriving the approximation for leveraged ETF returns?
From this article (and I've seen the same approximation in multiple places):

The formula for the long term compound annual growth rate of a
leveraged ETF cannot be written in terms of just the benchmark return
and volatility. It also involves terms containing the skewness and
kurtosis of the benchmark. Its derivation and form is published in the
paper that accompanies this article. It does not assume that benchmark
returns are Gaussian or that returns are continuous as do formulae
derived using Ito’s lemma.
But it turns out that for the world’s stock markets and for low levels
of leverage (up to about 3) the formula can be approximated by this
formula:
$$R = k\mu - \frac{k^2\sigma^2}{2(1 + k\mu)}      $$
where $R$ is the compound daily growth rate of the ETF, $k$ is the ETF
leverage, $\mu$ is the mean daily return of the benchmark, and $\sigma$ is the
daily volatility (i.e. standard deviation) of the daily return of the
benchmark.

How is this derived? Is there a reference for this approximation?
The linked article (Alpha Generation and Risk Smoothing Using Managed Volatility, by Tony Cooper, 2010) says:

It is derived using a Taylor series expansion (details available from
the author). It does not assume that benchmark returns are Gaussian or
that returns are continuous as do formulae derived using Itoís lemma.


It says "its derivation and form is published in the paper that accompanies this article."

@AKdemy, sorry I should've added more context—the published paper includes the quote I referenced in the answer, not sure if it's available ("details available from the author")

Looks to me like the Taylor approximation of the leveraged return.. I'll write a reply when I'm back home

Here is my thought: As mentioned in the paper, this is a Taylorseries of the function
$$ f(\mu)=ln(1+k\mu) $$
The first derivative of this is $f'(\mu)=\frac{k}{(1+k\mu)}$,
the second derivative is $f''(\mu)=-\frac{k^2}{(1+k\mu)^2}$,
the Taylorseries around $\mu_0=0$ is:
$$ f(\mu)=f(\mu_0)+f'(\mu_0)(\mu-\mu_0)+\frac{f''(\mu_0)}{2!}(\mu-\mu_0)^2+\dots$$
Using the derivatives from above
$$ ln(1+k\mu)=ln(1+k\mu_0)+\frac{k}{(1+k\mu_0)}(\mu-\mu_0)-\frac{k^2}{2(1+k\mu_0)^2}(\mu-\mu_0)^2 $$
The first term is zero, the second one is $k\mu$, the third one uses the notation for the variance $\sigma^2=\mu^2-2E(\mu_0)\mu-E(\mu_0)^2$
Finally we get the expression $ k\mu - \frac{k^2\sigma^2}{2(1 + k\mu)} $

Thank you. Where did you see $ f(\mu)=ln(1+k\mu)$?

@rb612 I found a hint on page 23, where it says "Figure 8 shows, on a log scale, the equity curve for the strategies and the equity curves for
the S&P 500 at 1x, 2x, 3x, 4x." log returns are quite common, check for example Hayden Brown (2023): "Long-term returns estimation of leveraged indexes and ETFs", there p. 6, 2nd. equation.

Hayden Brown article https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.03186

Thank for sharing this; was an interesting read.
You can find a more detailed discussion in this paper by the same authors. They have also cited references for the actual mentions and derivations in the same.
Hope it helps!

Note: This article was already linked at the end of the original post above.
